# Can I say copy_to_user()/copy_from_user() is a memcpy with access_ok()?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

We knew that for secure issues, we should use copy_to_user()/copy_from_user() if we want to do memory copy between user space and kernel space.

My question is, so the memcpy() should have better performance than copy_to_user()/copy_from_user()? Because memcpy() didn't do anything to try to protect the system, am I right?

If we don't care about secure issues, can we use memcpy() instead of copy_to_user()/copy_from_user() to get better performance? (it's a bad idea, I know, just ask if it's right)

Answer (score 3):

One answer: No, because security issues are never irrelevant in the kernel.

`memcpy()` in particular is a bad function to use because the third argument is a signed integer. If the user can in any way influence the value of this third parameter, you open yourself up to serious liability issues if someone attempts to copy a negative number of bytes.

Many a serious buffer overflow bugs have been due to the signed-ness of `memcpy()`

Another answer: No, because `copy_to_user()` and `copy_from_user()` don't just do `access_ok()`. Those first two functions make sure that the copy you are currently trying to achieve right now will succeed, or fail appropriately. This is not what `access_ok()` does for you. The documentation for `access_ok()` specifically says that this function doesn't guarantee that memory accesses will actually succeed:

```
Note that, depending on architecture, this function probably just 
checks that the pointer is in the user space range - after calling 
this function, memory access functions may still return -EFAULT.
```

For example, my most recent source code has, for x86, runtime checking that goes beyond `access_ok()`: https://lwn.net/Articles/612153/

Yet a third answer: `memcpy()` probably isn't much more efficient. You might save a few instructions here and there in principle, but those setup and checking instructions are going to be negligible once you're copying anything more than the smallest quantities of data.